# Progress Seeking audio location using HTML5 Progress

Tags: css, html, progress-bar

I am creating an audio player of sorts and i have run into a brick wall. I have added a progress bar that updates according to the song being played.

However, I want the progress bar to be clickable and to jump to the time of the track when its clicked (like every regular player).

```
<div class="music-stream-wrapper">

<ul class="music-stream">

<li>

  <div class="player-wrapper">

    <div class="album-art">
      <a href="#" title=""><img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000108593302-0ek7n6-t120x120.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="meta-controls">
      <div class="play-controls">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="track">
          <h4 class="title"><a href="" title="">Tail toddle - Unknown</a></h4>
          <span class="author"><a href="" title="">john.doe</a></span>
          <span class="uploaded">a few seconds ago</span>
        </div>
        <div class="spectrum">
          <div class="play-pause-button">
            <a href="#" class="play"></a>
            <a href="#" class="pause inactive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="spectrum-wrapper">
            <div id="spectrum_11"></div>
            <div class="progress">
              <progress value="0" max="1"></progress>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="intent">
        <ul class="buttons">
          <li><a href="#" class="like" title="Like">Like</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="download" title="Download">Download</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="share" title="Share">Share</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="meta">
          <li><span class="liked">&hearts; 13</span></li>
          <li><span class="played">&#9658; 123</span></li>
          <li><a href="" class="commented" title="Comments"><span>&hearts; 3</span></a></li>              
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</li>

</ul>

</div>

<audio src="http://tonycuffe.com/mp3/tailtoddle_lo.mp3" id="mockSong"></audio>
```

I have created a mock player in CodePen heres the url: [View in CodePen](http://codepen.io/CreativityKills/pen/EjapyX)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) slider and updating it dynamically as the track position changed.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you. try to evaluate what you desire for

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/8u76B/20/

### HTML

```
 <div id="progress"></div>
 <div id="back">back</div>
 <div id="cont">cont</div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
  //PROGRESS BAR
 $("#progress").progressbar({
       value: 0
    });
 //UPDATING PROGRESS BAR WHEN CONTINUE BUTTON CLICKED
    var currValue = 0,
    toValue = 0;
   $("#cont").button().click(function () {
  currValue = $("#progress").progressbar("value");
    if (currValue + 25 <= 100) {
    toValue = currValue + 25;
    animateProgress();
    }
});
 //DECREASING PROGRESS BAR WHEN GO BACK BUTTON CLICKED
$("#back").button().click(function () {
  currValue = $("#progress").progressbar("value");
  if (currValue - 25 >= 0) {
      toValue = currValue - 25;
      animateProgress();
   }
 });

function animateProgress() {
if (currValue < toValue) {
    $("#progress").progressbar("value", currValue + 1);
    currValue = $("#progress").progressbar("value");
    setTimeout(animateProgress, 4);
} else if (currValue > toValue) {
    $("#progress").progressbar("value", currValue - 1);
    currValue = $("#progress").progressbar("value");
    setTimeout(animateProgress, 4);
 }
}
```